# How use of getparameter in jsp function

Tags: java, jsp

how use of getParameter in function

```
<%! public void search(){

String name = request.getParameter("name");
}
%>
```

error accepted by this code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide more details in your question. Some things might be obvious for you but please consider that most of us do not live inside your head :)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The `request` is not a "global variable", but a parameter of the `_jspService` method of the class the JSP is compiled into. You have to pass it to your method as a parameter, i.e. the header should be `public void search(HttpServletRequest request) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do any business login on jsp.. but to resolve your issue, you can try below code:

```
<%!
public void search(HttpServletRequest request) {
       String name = request.getParameter("name");
}

//and while calling this on same jsp
search(request);
%>
```